# getting a permission error even after permission read_contacts is declared

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions

So I initially only wanted to access contact names, and I only declared my permission in the manifest. My code was working fine then. But now I'm trying out accessing the contact number too, and that's giving me the following in logcat:

```
    2019-11-05 18:56:02.738 30808-30919/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones from pid=5361, uid=10178 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
    at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:705)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:565)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:224)
    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:752)
2019-11-05 18:54:09.212 5113-5113/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.fresh, PID: 5113
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/2644i1d5681210d9c25a6.1450iSkype_108/738 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.android.fresh/com.example.android.fresh.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones from pid=5113, uid=10178 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4506)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4548)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones from pid=5113, uid=10178 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1950)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:432)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:847)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:762)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:720)
    at com.example.android.fresh.MainActivity.getContactNumber(MainActivity.java:163)
    at com.example.android.fresh.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:129)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4499)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4548) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2019-11-05 18:56:02.740 5361-5361/com.example.android.fresh E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.fresh, PID: 5361
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/2644i179d0ece8ca0b7f9.3789r1113-2916221214.1450iSkype_1113.1419r4429-2916221214.847r4510-2916221214/4513 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.android.fresh/com.example.android.fresh.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones from pid=5361, uid=10178 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4506)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4548)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones from pid=5361, uid=10178 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1950)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:432)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:847)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:762)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:720)
    at com.example.android.fresh.MainActivity.getContactNumber(MainActivity.java:163)
    at com.example.android.fresh.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:129)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4499)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4548) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This is the relevant code within getContactName()

```
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriContact, null, null, null, null);

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {

        contactName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));}
```

And the relevant code within getContactNumber()

```
   Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
            null, null, null);

    if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {

        contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    }

    cursorID.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact ID: " + contactID);

    // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
    Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

            new String[]{contactID},
            null);

    if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
        contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    returnval = true;
    }

    cursorPhone.close();
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to ask run time permission

Comment: use below answer it will help you

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Request code for READ_CONTACTS. It can be any number > 0.
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Read and show the contacts
        showContacts();
    }

    /**
     * Show the contacts in the ListView.
     */
    private void showContacts() {
        // Check the SDK version and whether the permission is already granted or not.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method
        } else {
            // Android version is lesser than 6.0 or the permission is already granted.
            getContactNames();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted
                showContacts();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we canot display the names", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read the name of all the contacts.
     *
     * @return a list of names.
     */
    private void getContactNames() {
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection    = new String[]          {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

        Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,  null, null);

        int indexName = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int indexNumber = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

        if(people.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
              String name   = people.getString(indexName);
              String number = people.getString(indexNumber);
              // add number to list
        // Do work...
           } while (people.moveToNext());
         }
         people.close();
    }
}
```